# Data for testing sequence tagging algorithm

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, research

I am currently performing research in field of sequence tagging algorithms and I need dataset to compare some algorithms like CRF on this dataset. I have already found CoNLL2000 POS recognition dataset, but I need something more general, with real numbers for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use our training data for a CRF we trained to label address components: https://github.com/datamade/usaddress/blob/master/training/labeled.xml